# Proper transition between SpriteKit Animations

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have an idle player animation and I want to do a smooth transition between some animations. The idle animation is the default one and from that transition I want to be able to switch to another state(let's say fight) and then back to idle. The code for the idle character animation is currently like :

```
self.addChild(playerAnimation)
playerAnimation.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
            SKAction.animateWithTextures(playerAnimationManager.idleManAnimation.textureArray, timePerFrame: 0.1)))
```

Now, this is scheduled to go on forever for now, but I would need to intercept it and add a new animation on top of that (which is the same character, in a new state). I was thinking that I should stop the idle animation, switch to the new one and then back to idle when finished but I am not convinced that this is the best way of chaining animations and I haven't really found a good resource explaining how to go about it.

Any suggestions ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how short your texture array is, you might be able to do this.

I will try to explain without code seeing how I use `objective C` and you use `Swift`

1. First make a property or variable that can be called by any subroutine in this class file. It should be `Boolean` and should be set to `NO`. You could call it `idleFlag`.
2. Next make a method that changes the animation to fight mode. This change would be by removing the idle animation and replacing it with the fight animation. This method also set's `idleFlag` to `NO`. Let's call the method "`beginFightAnim`"
3. And last, in your `repeatActionForEver` idle animation, right after your `animateWithTextures` animation, add a `runBlock` animation. In this block define a static variable (one that will be remembered in the calling of the block over and over) and increment it by +1, add an "if statement" that looks something like this -> `if (my_static_var == number_of_frames_in_texture_animations && idleFlag)`. And in the "if statement" set the static variable to 0 and call "`beginFightAnim`"

After this all you have to do to change the animation is set `idleFlag` to `YES`.

Hope it works!

If you have any problems, please comment below.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable solution indeed. Let me try that and see how that works, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I want to do a series of examples to make it easier to understand the matter. Suppose you have your node called `playerAnimation`, a typical atlasc with a plist where you have

```
player-idle1.png
player-idle2.png
player-idle3.png
...
```

If you want to intercept in real-time your animation to know what frame is running in that moment you can do:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
   if String(playerAnimation.texture).rangeOfString("player-idle") != nil {
      print(String(playerAnimation.texture))
   }
}
```

At this point, after you have assigned a "key" to your action (`withKey:"idleAnimation"`) you could stop your specific idle action when you preefer to start the other next animation.

Another good thing is to build a structure to know everytime your player status and modify this variable each time you launch a new action or animation:

```
enum PlayerStatus: Int {
    case Idle = 1
    case Fight = 2
    case Run = 3
    case Jump = 4
    case Die = 5
    ...
}

var currentStatus: PlayerStatus!
```

Comment: Does this work for you?  Last time I tried getting the texture from a sprite during an animateWithTextures event it would return the original texture, not the animated,   I ended up writing my own action to handle this for me.

Comment: Yes, tried to be secure before posting.I've used atlasc created by my folder atlas with all my frames, when you build the app and search inside the content package you find the atlasc. I can see all the frames names step by step during the animation so, for now, I don t know issues about it

Comment: the frame name is not what I was concerned with,  it is getting the actual texture you were using,  it is actually printing idle1, idle2, idle3..etc?

Comment: Yes man, exactly what I ve seen during animation, is printed in console debug in the same time, you see frame printed and showed, what do you mean?

Comment: I wonder if this got changed or fixed then,  maybe there was a different setting I had that caused a problem,  if I run into the issue again ill come back to you

Comment: Thank you, thats will be interesting! Ah, for this test I use always Swift 2.2 and Xcode 7.3